# Viewcontroller not presented on first time run

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Im attempting to get the view controller to present `InitialViewController` on the first time run and first time  only. However it appears with this message:

> Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Whats wrong with my code then ?

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
BOOL hasRunBefore = [defaults boolForKey:@"FirstRun"];

if (!hasRunBefore) {
    [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"FirstRun"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    UIViewController * InitialViewViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"view2"];
    [self presentViewController:InitialViewViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

else
{
    NSLog (@"Not the first time this controller has been loaded");



}
```

Comment: Where is this code that you're running? It should be in the first presented ViewController for your app.

Answer (score 0):

You need a key window. Usually, you have in your code `[window makeKeyAndVisible];`. This constitutes the windows hierarchy.

Comment: Where should I put it ?

Comment: Usually in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` of your AppDelegate. See, e.g. [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/ios-app-builder/getting-started-with-ios-views-and-view-controllers-part-1)

Comment: K Ill look at that. ill get back to you whether it works or not